# Why is the foo() function executed while not having been called?

Tags: php, function, if-statement, execute

I'm kind of new to PHP so please excuse the simplicity of my question in case it was,
I have a function `foo()` that always returns true, now my question is that while I have only checked the `true` being of `foo()` and not called the `foo()` function directly, how possibly did it execute then?
And is only PHP like this or it is the same say in JavaScript?

```
 $x = 10;
function foo() {
    global $x;
    if($x = 10) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

if(foo()) {
    echo 'Done foo() function!';
} else {
    echo 'Not done foo() function...';
}
```

Comment: `$nextFoo = foo();` ... executes the function. What did you expect?

Comment: fyi, `if($x = 10) {` _assigns_ a value, use `==` or `===` to compare values. If you set `$x = 12;` outside of your function it will also `return true`.

Comment: erm ... why is this tagged javascript?

Comment: Are you asking about PHP or JavaScript?

Comment: @brombeer Oh, I thought $nextFoo only held the function `foo()` in itself, I deleted the `$nextFoo = foo();` line and only passed the `foo()` in the condition of the if statement, and `foo()` still executes, now how did it execute?

Comment: Don't change your question, add any changes to it. The code would give you a "_Warning:  Undefined variable $foo..._" now, `$foo` is not set anywhere

Comment: Please stop changing the code so drastically. You're making the comments obsolete and the answers too.

Comment: @brombeer Yes, typing `$foo` instead of `foo()` was a typo, but now where is `foo()` called to be executed?

Comment: `if(foo()) {` executes the function, might want to find a basic tutorial on how PHP/functions work, SO is for specific coding problems, not teaching the basics

Comment: @evolutionxbox Alright I won't change it again since I did my final edit.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you did called foo in `if(foo())` this line. Essentially what you did in this line is called `foo` and checked its return value with `if`. If you want to check if `foo` function is executed or not you can keep a flag as global variable and and set it to `true` in the function somewhere like this

```
$foo_executed = false;
function foo (){
    global $foo_executed;
    // your code here
    $foo_executed = true;
}

//execute foo
foo();
if ($foo_executed){
   echo "foo executed";
}
```

This behavior is also common in other programming languages. You can follow this tutorial to learn more about functions. good luck!

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HvxQww-7NGA

Comment: This answer is now out-of-date since `$nextFoo = foo();` is now removed from the question

Comment: This code will output nothing. What is that function for?